# How to add two kind of values from the same columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a table called Expenses in MySQL data store. The table structure and data are given below:

```
   ---------------
   |YEAR|Expenses|
   |----|--------|
   |2015|503K    |
   |----|--------|
   |2015|406K    |
   |----|--------|
   |2015|1.2M    |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|700K    |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|900K    |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|3.2M    |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|4.7M    |
   ---------------
```

I need to take the sum of all values ending with 'K', group the result by year and multiply the result with 1000. Likewise, I need to take the sum of all the values ending with 'M', group the result by year and multiply the result with 1000000. Finally, I need to add the results of both K values and M values and obtain the total expenses for every year. My final table should look like this in two different formats:

```
   ---------------
   |YEAR|Expenses|
   |----|--------|
   |2015|2109000 |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|9500000 |
   |----|--------|
```

or

```
   ---------------
   |YEAR|Expenses|
   |----|--------|
   |2015|2.1M    |
   |----|--------|
   |2016|9.5M    |
   |----|--------|
```

Any suggestions or guidelines?

Comment: Sure.  My suggestion is to _not_ store numerical data with which you intend to do arithmetic as text.  E.g. store `700K` as a _number_ `700000`.  By the way, is this homework?  If so, you will need to show us some effort if you want help here.  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Sure. I can understand and I would like to inform you that I am working on this problem now. This is not a homework. It is a practice problem that I am working on so that I can get myself equipped with MySQL and analytical script writing skills. A quick update for you. MySQL can add values ending with K and M and you don't need to convert them to a number.

Comment: Currently, I am up writing the concept till here. (SELECT A.YEAR, SUM(A.EXPENSES) AS KSUM
FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.EXPENSES LIKE '%K'
GROUP BY A.YEAR) AS FIRSTQ

Comment: If MySQL can really add those numbers, then all you need is a `GROUP BY` query, aggregating over the year.

Comment: -- Calculate the sum of the expenses ending with K
(SELECT A.YEAR, SUM(A.EXPENSES) AS KSUM
FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.EXPENSES LIKE '%K'
GROUP BY A.YEAR) AS FIRSTQ 

-- Calculate the sum of the expenses ending with M
(SELECT B.YEAR, SUM(B.EXPENSES) AS MSUM
FROM TABLE B
WHERE B.EXPENSES LIKE '%M'
GROUP BY B.YEAR) AS SECONDQ

I need to add KSUM and MSUM now and group them by year that are common
in the results of both the queries (year is common).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your suggestion is to clean up the data converting text to numeric first and add them. Is that right?

Comment: I think this is your only option.  How can you even insert `503K` into a numerical column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Expenses is not a numeric column. The data type is varchar. That is the complexity of this problem statement!

Comment: You just told me that `MySQL can add values ending with K and M and you don't need to convert them to a number` ... is this true or is this not true?

Comment: If I perform`SELECT SUM(Expenses) FROM TABLE WHERE Expenses LIKE '%K' GROUP BY YEAR;` it gives me the result 909 for the year 2015 and 1600 for the year 2016 (without K appended to it). That is the reason I am multiplying the result with 1000 for K values.

Comment: Here is a hint: Use substring operations to separate the numbers from the units.  Then do the arithmetic and rollup the sum for each year.

Comment: If I use the substring to separate the numbers from the units and add them, it doesn't give accurate results and I have a reason for it. First of all there are two kinds of units for each year (K and M). Using substring to separate numbers from K and M and adding them will give results like `910.2` for the year `2015` and `1607.9` for the year 2016. That is not an accurate result! I have to get `2109000` or `2.1M` for `2015` and `9500000` or `9.5M`for `2016`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT
    year,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN expenses like '%K' then expenses*1000
            WHEN expenses like '%M' then expenses*1000000
        END) AS expenses
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    year
ORDER BY
    year;
```

Hope it helps. Interesting that mysql lets you add values ending with non-numeric characters. Didn't know that one.

Comment: If you want the looks of the second table you posted, just operate with the sum and concatenate an 'M'. Did not try it, but should not be hard.

Comment: That's perfect. I used the following query and it works like a charm! `SELECT
    year,
    concat(sum(
        CASE
            WHEN expenses like '%K' then expenses*1000
            WHEN expenses like '%M' then expenses*1000000
        END)/1000000, 'M') AS expenses
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    year;` Thanks and I appreciate it @jzeta

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if mysql does allow you to add values ending with non-numeric characters I would suggest you don't get into the habit of thinking that other sql dialects do the same.

```
select year,
         cast(
         sum(case when instr(expenses,'k') > 0.0 then
                cast(replace(expenses,'k','') as decimal(15,2)) * 1000
                when instr(expenses,'m') > 0.0 then
                cast(replace(expenses,'m','') as decimal(15,2)) * 1000000
         end 
         ) 
         as int ) en
from t
group by year
```

Result

```
+------+---------+
| year | en      |
+------+---------+
| 2015 | 2109000 |
| 2016 | 9500000 |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set, 7 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: got you. Now, I am trying to solve different questions using MySQL scripts. More predominantly on Set Based Approaches using joins and sub-queries. I know it would differ on other database engines. Thanks to you too for providing an effective solution! :)